# What are these mushrooms growing in the shade in Houston, Texas?

Tags: identification, mushrooms

What kind of Mushrooms are these? I found them growing in my yard near Houston, Texas (UDSA Zone 9a).

*Click on any picture for full size*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like some kind of funnelcap - possibly related to Lepista flaccida?

Comment: Do these smell of anything, bruise, or leak fluid when damaged? Is there much stem to speak of and if yes does it have a ring like structure anywhere? This information would help with identification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Alpar is on to something, and I'll guess his suggestion of [*Lepista flaccida*](http://www.first-nature.com/fungi/lepista-flaccida.php) is correct, as it is widespread throughout Europe and North America, and both the color and form are variable, to the point where people have tried to distinguish individual spores.

> Many people have difficulty identifying the Tawny Funnel, and this is hardly surprising because in both shape and colour it is very variable. Many authors have tried to separate it into a number of distinct taxa, either at species or variety level.

*Lepista flaccida* is edible, although of poor flavor.